# ORing of statements

Tags: c++

Where does  the difference  lies between these two style of writing. The compiler is showing correct answer in first case and wrong in second case.

1.

```
    string s[6];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++) cin>>s[i];
    if(s[0]==s[2] && s[0]==s[4])  { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if(s[0]==s[2] && s[0]==s[5])  { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[0]==s[3] && s[0]==s[5])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[0]==s[3] && s[0]==s[4])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[1]==s[2] && s[1]==s[4])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[1]==s[2] && s[1]==s[5])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[1]==s[3] && s[1]==s[4])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
    else if((s[1]==s[3] && s[1]==s[5])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }

     else cout<<"NO"<<endl;
```

and

2.

```
string s[6];
for(int i=0;i<6;i++) cin>>s[i];
if(s[0]==s[2]||s[0]==s[3])
{
    if((s[0]==s[4]||s[0]==s[5])) { cout<<"YES"<<endl; }
}
else if(s[1]==s[2]||s[1]==s[3])
{
    if((s[1]==s[4]||s[1]==s[5])) cout<<"YES"<<endl;
}
 else cout<<"NO"<<endl;
```

Comment: please generate/post an executable file that displays the problem.   As it is, we have to guess when we try to re-create the problem.

Comment: the function: 'cin' is not in C, however it is in C++.   Strongly suggest 1) learn the difference between 'and' and 'or' (boolean logic)   2) change the tag from 'c' to 'c++'

Comment: @user3629249: No, don't "post an executable file".

Comment: Don't write code like this. At all. Ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this scenario

```
 s[1]=s[2] and s[1]=s[4] and s[0]=s[2]//rest everything we don't care about
```

Code1 will output `yes`.Good.
Now consider code2

```
    if(s[0]==s[2]||s[0]==s[3])//s[0]==s[2] so we enter here
   {
          if((s[0]==s[4]||s[0]==s[5])) //this condition is not true so `yes` is not printed
           { cout<<"YES"<<endl; } 
   }
   else if(s[1]==s[2]||s[1]==s[3])//now we won't enter here as we already entered if
   {
          if((s[1]==s[4]||s[1]==s[5])) cout<<"YES"<<endl;
   }
```

So code2 outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some condition in the 2nd:

Like this:

```
if(s[0]==s[2] && s[1]==[5])
```

What will be the output of this??

In every `if-else if` condition you have to add a `else` condition.

In code:

```
if(s[0]==s[2]||s[0]==s[3])
{
    if((s[0]==s[4]||s[0]==s[5]))
    {
        cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"No"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an else condition at the end